# How to load view and title together using AngularJS and Ionic on Android?

Tags: android, angularjs, ionic-framework

I have an app running on AngularJS and Ionic and I have a problem with state transition with Android devices but not on iPhone/iOS.

One page is quite large and when I navigate from the home screen to this page the header gets loaded first and after 2-3 seconds the actual view changes.

I tried adding `ng-cloak` to the `ion-view` but this doesn't solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by that your view is getting changed? Also in which versions of Android are you facing this problem?

Unfortunately it seems a problem very device oriented. You could try to change some elements to enhance perfomance like changing your ng-repeat for collection-repeat.

The best way you could try to improve your performance in Android comes to the cost of weight in your App. You could try using Crosswalk Webview Plugin. This not only provides you the great webview capabilities where your native webview lacks the performance but also it is providing feature constancy across Android 4.0+ Platforms.

See this:

http://blog.ionic.io/crosswalk-comes-to-ionic/

https://github.com/crosswalk-project/cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview

Comment: view in the sense the content of the page.initially the header with back button is getting changed and the data is home screen data for 2-3 seconds. after which the content gets changed to the actual page content. I have tested this in android 6.0 and experiencing this problem.